# Change SQL decimal delimiter

Tags: sql, decimal, locale, sqlanywhere

I am trying to import data into my table using

```
INPUT INTO
```

The problem is my decimals is using `,` as a delimiter, and it expects `.`. So it won't work!

How can i change this? Search and replace in the input file is not an option!

I am using SQL Anywhere 10

Comment: Might be worth asking on the SQL Anywhere Stack Exchange site: http://sqla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's possible to change the decimal delimiter. You could either preprocess the file (which I know you said is not an option) or load it into a temporary table with the decimal column defined as a string and then use an insert from the temporary table to your real table, performing the necessary conversion at that point.